# The UICollectionViewCell do not flow according to common sense

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I set my UICollectionView's delegate methods:

```
#pragma mark - collectionView delegate

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    //CGPoint point = self.collectionView.frame.origin;
    //CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, self.collectionView.bounds.size.width, 70*2);


    // height

    /*_heightOfCollectionView.constant = kHeight_Collection_Cell * 6;

    _heightOfContents.constant = collectionView.frame.origin.y + 230 + _heightOfCollectionView.constant;*/

    return 12;//_recommendDataArr.count;


}

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    float width = (self.view.bounds.size.width / 2);
    float height = 89; // 89

    return CGSizeMake(width, height);
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    HomeGMCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"HomeGMCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"HomeGMCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }



    return cell;
}
```

The `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex` is `0`:

And you see I return the Cell's size's width is:

```
(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2)  // attention: no matter is `(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2) - ?(?=1,2,3,4)` it all get the below issue:
```

But I get the result:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

It did not flow to the 2 cols. it flows to one flow.

But if I set the Cell's size's width  `(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2) - 5` in the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method, I will get the below effect:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

It shows two cols, it my requirement, but however there comes an other issue is, the right has a `10px`'s space.

How to avoid this issue in UICollectionView?

Comment: Collections views nature is this. Try to use collectionView frame instead of self.view.frame or else change cell size width in such a way that it got enough space. It's all depends on how you are giving cell size. Try to change there only.

Comment: ...and the `minimumInteritemSpacing` should be `0` as well, I presume, or you need to consider that value when you calculate the cell's width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method for padding .

```
 - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return  CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH/2 -5, 89);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return 10.0f;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10.0f;
}
```

Comment: Still get the issue, my brother.